# Vue datepicker and submitting selected date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

I'm using the [`vue-date-picker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-date-picker) package in my laravel application, and upon selecting a date from the datepicker I can see in my vue developer tools `pickedValue` with the selected date. Currently my code is plain:

```
<datepicker></datepicker>
```

But I'm wondering, is the `pickedValue` the correct syntax to use for submitting this in a form? Do I need an `onChange` event, or can I just use `datepicker.pickedValue` or something similar? I just want to set the picked date to a variable for an axios post.

UPDATE:

```
<div v-cloak v-if="isScheduledTask">
  <datepicker v-model="pickedValue" name="pickedValue" id="pickedValue" ></datepicker>
</div>

data() {
  return{
    pickedValue:'',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use you local data property and pass it as a `:value` prop. Getting inner state of component through `this.$refs.datepicker.pickedValue` is considered a bad practice. It's considered standard de-facto to use props and events to communicate between parent and child components in Vue.js. There are some drawbacks of using your approach:

1. You can't set the value of the `datepicker` outside.
2. Another developer would be confused with such approach.
3. You are breaking one way data flow approach.
4. Your code is prone to bug, because that's local component variables. Every time name of this property can change.

Alert from Vue.js docs:

> Use `$parent` and `$children` sparingly - they mostly serve as an
>   escape-hatch. Prefer using props and events for parent-child
>   communication.

#### Update

**DO NOT EVER DO IT AGAIN**

In your case you have no other options, but to access it through `refs`.

```js
this.$refs.datepicker.pickedValue
```

```
<div>
  <datepicker ref="datepicker" value="2018-9-5"></datepicker>
</div>

...
methods: {
  sendForm() {
    console.log(`Picked date ${this.$refs.datepicker.pickedValue}`)
  }
}
...
```

#### Update

It's very bad pattern, but you have no choice working with library that does not emit **ANY** events.

**DON'T DO IT EVER AGAIN!!!**

```html
<datepicker ref="datepicker" @click.native="method"></datepicker>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    value: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  method() {
    this.value = this.$refs.datepicker.pickedValue
  },
},
```

Comment: I don't have an actual data property now, I'm just using the out of the box datepicker. Are you saying make a data property that holds pickedValue and pass that as a :value?

Comment: @TomN., yes that's it.

Comment: Uhh... searching through the src of that component, I have found that component does not emit any events :( .So in that case your approach is right.

Comment: Ok so I updated with my current code but when I console log pickedValue it's just empt. But the actual pickedValue is showing in the vue debugger

Comment: @TomN., updated the answer. Just  tested in my project. Can access it it through `$refs.datepicker.pickedValue`.

Comment: ok I see what you mean but I"m doing this in my ```data(){return{pickedValue: $this.refs.datepicker.pickedValue}}``` and it's coming back undefined. I have value="" in my datepicker instance

Comment: actually that breaks the whole page load

Comment: Do not do this. Just access  `$refs.datepicker` where you want to  access the `pickedValue`. Don't  do this in `data()`.

Comment: But i'll need the value with my other form data in data(){return{}}. That's my issue is I need to be able so set the selected date to a variable for an axios post call